# Mixed-Up cake recipe instructions

Tags: baking, dough, dessert

Please help!!  I am making a dessert, I make this all the time and this is the only time I have ever done this. The recipe is supposed to be stirred but I pulled out my electric mixer. I need the texture to be clumpy and kind of  dry because I am making a crust.  The recipe reads: “In a mixing bowl, **stir** together the cake mix, melted and cooled butter, and 2 eggs. Line a 9x12 baking dish with parchment paper and press the dough into the bottom in an even layer’. How can I fix this? I didn’t realize what I’d done until I was removing the mixer from the bowl and thought, “this doesn’t look right, what happened?”  The dough was almost in liquid form and I need it to be solid. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you did [or didn't] do that you should[n't] have. Also, I would have far more serious concerns for driving an hour & a half on no sleep than I would over getting a cake right.

Comment: My husband will be driving, and I hope to catch a nap while the main course is baking, my husband said he will keep an eye on the food for me. I used an electric mixer instead of stirring the ingredients. My dough is usually clumpy and able to mold into the pan but since I used the mixer my dough is soft and just kind of runny instead of solid

Comment: Take a deep breath, preferably a nap and remember it's just a cake. For your question we need more information, it's not clear what the directions were and what you actually did instead.

Comment: Then could you edit to clarify your actual question & to remove the other aspects, which are not directly relevant to the cooking issue itself.

Comment: Glad you weren't driving! :) Any chance you could update us on how it came out, what did/didn't work? Hope all went well and you have caught up on sleep.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure that it can be saved ... but that doesn't mean that it won't end up being something good as-is.  Unless that's your only dish the size you need, I'd just throw it in the oven as-is, and see what happens.

As it's a crust, you might look to see if you have anything that you can use for crumbs (cookies, graham crackers, ground nuts, I've even had ones made with boxed cereal and brown sugar) and make a quick crumb crust.

You could also flip things upside down -- take whatever was intended as the filling, and add a streusel / crumble topping ... or some other buckle, betty, etc. type thing where the crust-like layer is on the top.

As you might not have time to start again, it's possible the crust might come out like a giant cookie ... if so, pop it out of the pan to let it cool while you bake the filling, then crumble it up on top of the dessert once it's out of the oven.